# How to pass model and another parameter to a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, parameters, model, viewmodel

I may have done this already... and I might just be missing something simple, but essentially I just want to be able to do this...

```
public ActionResult ContinueProcess(Model m, int id){


}
```

I just want to pass the model and another parameter at the same time. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would certainly create a **ViewModel** to handle this

```
public class ContinueProcessViewModel
{
   public int ID { set;get;}
   public Model ContinueProcess { set;get;}
}
```

Return this ViewModel in your get action method'

```
public ActionResult ContinueProcess(int id)
{
  ContinueProcessViewModel objVM=new ContinueProcessViewModel();
  objVm.ID=id;
  return View(objVM);
}
```

And in your View, Have a HTMLelement(textbox/hidden) to hold the value of this

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.ID)
```

Now you should be able to acceess this in your httppost action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ConitnueProcess(ContineProcessViewModel objVM)
{
  //Check objVm.ID here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Either with a ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel {
    public Model MyModel {get;set;}
    public int ParameterId {get;set;}
}
```

used as Model of your View,

or with a ViewBag

```
ViewBag.ParameterId= id;
```